# Show that the Euler characteristic of a chain complex is equal to the Euler characteristic of its homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

**Let $C_*$ be a chain complex such that each $C_i$ is a torsion-free, finite-range abelian group with $C_i=0$ for all $i<0$. Suppose that $C_i=0$ for all $i$ is large enough. The Euler characteristic of $C_*$ chain complex is defined as $$\chi(C_*)=\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^iRank(C_i)$$ Prove that $$\chi(C_*)=\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^iRank(H_i(C_*))$$**

I have to prove that $\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^iRank(C_i)=\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^iRank(H_i(C_*))$, I think that one way to do this is by showing that $Rank(C_i)=Rank(H_i(C_*))$ but I do not know if this is true in general, in a nutshell, I want to show that the cardinality of the base of any $C_i$ is the same as the cardinality of the basis of the corresponding homology, how can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Don't you mean $\textrm{Rank}(C_i)$ etc.?

Comment: @user482152 A counter-example to your guess as to how the proof would go: Say $C_* = \cdots {\mathbb Z}\to  {\mathbb Z} \cdots$, where the written arrow is multiplication by $2$, and all the unwritten $C_i$ are identically zero. Assuming that rank of a finitely generated abelian group $A$ means the dimension of the (free) quotient $A/A_{\rm tors}$: the rank of$\mathbb Z$ is $1$. On the other hand, the homology of $C_*$ is $\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z$, which has rank $0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown 
If that is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rk}}$
Consider the short exact sequences for $i\in \mathbb Z$.

$$0\to Z_i \to C_i \stackrel{d}\to B_{i-1} \to 0$$
$$0\to B_i  \to Z_i  \to H_i  \to 0$$

From them it follows that for each $i\in \mathbb Z$,
$$ \rank C_i=\rank Z_i + \rank B_{i-1}$$
$$\rank H_i  = \rank Z_i-\rank B_i$$

Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^i \rank H_i&= \sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^i \rank Z_i-\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^i \rank B_i\\
 &=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^i \rank Z_i+\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^{i-1} \rank B_i\\
&=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^i \rank C_i.
\end{align*}

This proof works in general for any map $\chi$ from some class of modules to integers which is additive on short exact sequences, meaning that whenever 
$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$
is exact, $\chi(A) + \chi(C) = \chi(B)$.

Answer (score 5):

Your chain complex looks like
$$0\to C_n\to C_{n-1}\to\cdots\to C_0\to0$$
where the $C_i$ are nonzero outside this range. Proceed by induction
on $n$. Call this complex $\mathbf C$. Let $\mathbf{C}'$ be the subcomplex
$$0\to0\to C_{n-1}\to\cdots\to C_0\to0.$$
Then there is a short exact sequence of complexes
$$0\to\mathbf{C}'\to\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}''\to0$$
where $C''$ consists just of $C_n$ in dimension $n$. This gives a long
exact sequence of homology. This starts
$$0\to H_n(\mathbf{C})\to C_n\to H_{n-1}(\mathbf{C'})\to H_{n-1}(\mathbf{C})\to0$$
so that
$$\textrm{rank}(H_n(\mathbf{C}))
-\textrm{rank}(C_n)+\textrm{rank}(H_{n-1}(\mathbf{C'}))-\textrm{rank}(H_{n-1}(\mathbf{C}))=0.\tag{1}$$
For $k<n-1$ another piece of the long exact sequence is
$$0\to H_{k}(\mathbf{C'})\to H_{k}(\mathbf{C})\to0$$
so that
$$\textrm{rank}(H_k(\mathbf{C'}))=\textrm{rank}(H_k(\mathbf{C})).
\tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2) one gets the relation between Euler characteristics:
$$\chi(\mathbf{C})=\chi(\mathbf{C'})+(-1)^n\textrm{rank}(C_n)$$
which gives the inductive step.

Comment: @Lord Why there is a short exact sequence of complexes?
$$0\to\mathbf{C}'\to\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}''\to0$$

what does it mean that $C''$ consists just of $C_n$ in dimension $n$.?

Comment: The complex $\mathbf{C}''$ looks like $\cdots0\to C_n\to0\to\cdots$.