# Show that $\bigoplus_{i \text{ even}}C_i=\bigoplus_{i\text{ odd}}C_i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

**Let $C_*$ be a chain complex such that each $C_i$ is a torsion-free, finite-range abelian group with $C_i=0$ for all $i<0$. Suppose that $C_i=0$ for all $i$ is sufficiently large and that for all $i$ there exists an integer $N_i\geq1$ such that $N_i(H_i(C_*))=0$, that is, each $H_i(C_*)$ is a torsion group. Show that $$\bigoplus_{i \text{ even}}C_i=\bigoplus_{i\text{ odd}}C_i$$**

I do not know how to solve this problem, I would appreciate any suggestions. We have to
$$...\overset{\partial}{\rightarrow}C_{n+1}\overset{\partial}{\rightarrow}C_{n}\overset{\partial}{\rightarrow}C_{n-1}\overset{\partial}{\rightarrow}...$$

where each $C_i$ has a base with a finite amount of elements, say $B_i$ and we also have $\partial(\partial(c_i))=0$ for all $c_i\in B_i$. How can I use all this to define an isomorphism between $\bigoplus_{i \text{ even}}C_i$ and $\bigoplus_{i\text{ odd}}C_i$? Thank you.

Comment: It's a standard fact in homological algebra that the alternating sum of the ranks of the chain group in a finite chain complex of f.g. abelian groups is equal to the alternating sum of the ranks of the homology groups. This is algebraic meaning of homology-invariance of Euler characteristic, if you like. You can try to prove/use this.

Comment: @BalarkaSen 
Yes,  I know this fact and here I found a proof of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807224/show-that-the-euler-characteristic-of-a-chain-complex-is-equal-to-the-euler-char?rq=1, but I do not know how to use this to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complex is of the form

$$
0 \to C_n \to \cdots \to C_1 \to C_0 \to 0
$$

and each $C_i$ is free as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, i.e. for each $i$ we have a non-negative integer $r_i$ such that $C_i \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{r_i}$ via some isomorphism $f_i : C^i \to \mathbb{Z}^{r_i}$. If we define $d_i := f_{i-1}\partial_if_i^{-1}$, it is easy to see that $f_\bullet : (C_\bullet,\partial) \to (\mathbb{Z}^{r_\bullet},d_\bullet)$ is a chain complex isomorphism. Hence we can reduce this to the case

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}^{r_n} \to \cdots \to \mathbb{Z}^{r_1} \to \mathbb{Z}^{r_0} \to 0.
$$

Note that by a rank argument, we will have $\bigoplus_{\text{$k$ odd}}\mathbb{Z}^{r_k} \simeq \bigoplus_{\text{$k$ even}}\mathbb{Z}^{r_k}$ if and only if $\sum_{\text{$k$ odd}}{r_k}$ = $\sum_{\text{$k$ even}}{r_k}$. This is equivalent to having that

$$
\chi(C_\bullet) = \chi(\mathbb{Z}^{r_\bullet}) = \sum_{k \geq 0}(-1)^k \operatorname{rk}\mathbb{Z}^{r_k} = \sum_{k \geq 0}(-1)^k r_k = 0.
$$

As said in the comments, it is a well known fact that the alternating sum of ranges of each $C_i$ coincides with the alternating sum of the ranges of each $H_i(C_\bullet)$. Thus, what we are being asked to prove is equivalent to proving $\sum_{k \geq 0}(-1)^k \operatorname{rk}{H}_k(C_\bullet) = 0$, and the latter follows from the fact that each homology group is of torsion.

Comment: Hola Guido, yo creo que $d_i=f_{i-1}\partial_i f_i^{-1}$ en vez de lo que pusiste, estoy en lo correcto? La verdad no entiendo por que $\bigoplus_{\text{$k$ odd}}\mathbb{Z}^{r_k} \simeq \bigoplus_{\text{$k$ even}}\mathbb{Z}^{r_k}$ if and only if $\sum_{\text{$k$ odd}}{r_k}$ = $\sum_{\text{$k$ even}}{r_k}$, tienes algun argumento para probar esto? por que esto es verdad?

Comment: You're right about the first equality, my bad. I have fixed it. As for the second fact, this is the same argument one makes when proving that two $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension (cont.)

Comment: Note that $\bigoplus_{j}\mathbb{Z}^{r_j} = \mathbb{Z}^{(\sum_j r_j)}$, we simply map each $e_i$ in the direct sum to $e_i$ in the latter. Now, in general $\mathbb{Z}^r \simeq \mathbb{Z}^s$ iff $d = s$. Sufficiency is evident as in that case, we have equality. As for necessity, if these modules are isomorphic, then their ranks coincide, which is precisely to say that $r = s$. (I've tried to keep this in English as the site rules mandate, but feel free to ask if anything is not clear, conceptually or otherwise).

Comment: To expand on the equality of the last comment: an explicit map is to send the $i$-th canonical vector of $\mathbb{Z}^{r_j}$ to the $(\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}r_k + i)$-canonical vector of $\mathbb{Z}^{\sum_j r_j}$. This induces a map into the latter from the direct sum, which is bijective.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so explicit, I value that much, I only have one last question and that is because if the homology group is torsion, then why $\sum_{k \geq 0}(-1)^k \operatorname{rk}{H}_k(C_\bullet) = 0$? (Do you have social networks so we can talk better and solve doubts?)

Comment: I don't have any social media, butI think you can make a chat directly here. The sum is zero because of a much stronger fact: each term is zero. This is because the rank of a f.g. abelian group can be defined as the rank of its free part (think of the decomposition of finitely generated abelian groups). Thus, torsion groups have zero rank (their free part is $0$).