# Chain Complexes show property $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}\dim(V_{i})=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}\dim(H_{i}(C))$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

With a finite chain of Complex $\Bbb C$, one defines a sequence of homomorphism

$0\xrightarrow{\text{f}_{n+1}}V_{n}\xrightarrow{\text{f}_{n}}\dots \xrightarrow{\text{f}_{2}}V_{1}\xrightarrow{\text{f}_{1}}V_{0}\xrightarrow{\text{f}_{0}}0$,
with a property $f_{i}\circ f_{i+1}=0$, meaning $\mathrm{Im}(f_{i+1})\subset \ker(f_{i})$.

The quotient vector space

$H_{i}(C)=\ker(f_{i})/\mathrm{Im}(f_{i+1})$

is called the $i$-th homology of the complex. Show that if all $V_{i}$ are finite, then

$\sum^{n}_{i=0}(-1)^{i}\dim(V_{i})=\sum^{n}_{i=0}(-1)^{i}\dim(H_{i}(C))$

My try:

I rewrote the sum as

$\sum^{n}_{i=0}\dim(H_{i}(C)) = dim(\ker(V_0)/\mathrm{Im}(f_1)) - \dim(\ker(V_1)/\mathrm{Im}(f_2)) + \dim(\ker(V_2)/\mathrm{Im}(f_3) - \dim(\ker(V_3)/\mathrm{Im}(f_4) \pm \dots $

Since every $V_{i}$ is finite we know that

$\dim(V_{i}/U_{i}) = \dim(V_{i}) - \dim(U_{i})$. Obviously are $kern(f_i)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(f_i)$ also finite, so $\dim(\ker(f_{i})/k_{i+1}) = \dim(\ker(f_{i})) - \dim(k_{i+1})$.

So we can rewrite

$\sum^{n}_{i=0}\dim(H_{i}(C)) = (\dim(\ker(V_0))-\mathrm{Im}(f_1)) - (\dim(\ker(V_1))-(\mathrm{Im}(f_2)) + (\dim(\ker(V_2))-(\mathrm{Im}(f_3)) - (\dim(\ker(V_3))-(\mathrm{Im}(f_4)) \pm \dots $

We also know that if $V$ finite $n$-dimensional Vektor space and $f: V \rightarrow W$, then

$\dim(\ker(f))+\mathrm{Im}(f)=n.$ So the summation above can be rewritten as

$\sum^{n}_{i=0}\dim(H_{i}(C)) = \dim(\ker(V_0))- (\mathrm{Im}(f_1)) + \dim(\ker(V_1))-(\mathrm{Im}(f_2) + \dim(kern(V_2)))-(\mathrm{Im}(f_3) + \dim(\ker(V_3))- \pm \dots  = \dim(\ker(V_{0})) -V_1+V_2-V_3 \pm \dots$

If the steps done by now are correct, I still end up with $\dim(\ker(V_{0}))$ and the endpoint $\mathrm{Im}(f_{n+1})$

Could anyone let me know if the steps by now are correct? If yes what how would I deal with the last step? If no, what I missed?

thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807224/show-that-the-euler-characteristic-of-a-chain-complex-is-equal-to-the-euler-char

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks, i guess im not looking to copy the assignment, but for hints whether my way of proving it is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, your notation is a bit sloppy, so that makes it more difficult to check.